# How to search in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, where-clause

Here is my table:

```
// table
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    |
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 3    |
| 4  | 2    | 1    |
| 5  | 2    | 2    |
| 6  | 3    | 1    |
| 7  | 3    | 2    |
| 8  | 3    | 3    |
| 9  | 3    | 4    |
| 10 | 3    | 5    |
+----+------+------+
```

Now I want to search in both `col1` and `col2`. Something like this:

```
 select * from table where col1,col2 IN (1,2);
```

And I want this **output:**

```
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    |
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 3    |
| 4  | 2    | 1    |
| 5  | 2    | 2    |
| 6  | 3    | 1    |
| 7  | 3    | 2    |
+----+------+------+
```

Well, My problem is on this part: `... where col1,col2 IN (1,2)`. How can I solve it?

**Note:** I can do that like this: `... where col1 IN (1,2) or ,col2 IN (1,2)`. But this this way, I have to create two separate index on each column. While I want a query which need to a group-index like this: `KEY NameIndex (col1, col2)`

Comment: Try `WHERE 1 IN (col1,col2) OR 2 IN (col1,col2)`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Ok tnx, just your solution is better than this? `where col1 IN (1,2) or ,col2 IN (1,2)` ?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see if the predicates I recommend use your composite index. If not, then what I'm suggesting is useless.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Ah I see, yes I like to eliminate two separated single index! Just one thing, There is a approach to doing that something like this? `WHERE (col1,col2) IN (1,2)` ?

Comment: This should be written as `WHERE (col1,col2) IN ((1,2))`. This is equivalent to `col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2`, so it doesn't do what you actually want.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ow! that means `AND`. well as you said yeah it is not what I want. anyway thanks buddy :-)

Comment: I also doubt that my suggestion works. I think you are going to need two separate indices on `col1` and `col2` because this is the very nature of your lookup. Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for an explanation on how composite indices work.

Comment: Try it,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Is `UNION` an option? Two select statements for col1 and col2

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam That's actually a horrible idea. Full-Text is for text, not numbers. Also it does not index the words with less than 4 characters.

Comment: @ozy No, It is just one `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this, correct?

```
WHERE col1 IN (1,2)
   OR col2 IN (1,2)
```

If so, turn the `OR` into a `UNION`.  (This is a common optimization trick.)

```
( SELECT ... WHERE col1 IN (1,2) )
UNION DISTINCT  -- since there are likely to be dups
( SELECT ... WHERE col2 IN (1,2) );
```

And provide the optimal index for each `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(col1),
INDEX(col2)
```

A composite index of those two columns will *not* suffice.

(Appologies -- this is probably a summary of best of the many disjointed comments.)

Comment: OOC, why wouldn't you just go with the `WHERE col1 IN (x) OR vol2 IN (x)` concept?

Comment: No index will be used in that construct.  The `UNION`, though messier, can optimizer each of the `SELECTs`.

Comment: OTOH, if most columns values are 1 or 2, my SQL won't use the indexes either.  This is because it is usually faster to do a table scan than to use a not-so-selective index.  In that case, `OR` would be faster.

Comment: So I guess the answer (as always with SQL), is the SELECT+UNION idea should be faster but you can't beat comparing the plans ;)